# command failed (exitstatus=1): --load-error-handling ignore --header-html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using [PDFKit gem](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) to generate `PDFs` in `Rails`, I'm trying to add a header in my `PDF`, I tried using `header_html` while generating the `PDF`, ends up with an error

here is the error:

```
RuntimeError - command failed (exitstatus=1): /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf --page-size Letter --encoding UTF-8 --load-error-handling ignore --header-html
```

here is my code:

```
    view_generator = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.root.join('app/views'))
    pdf_kit = PDFKit.new(view_generator.render(partial: 'field_set_answers/pdf_feedback', locals: { field_set_answer: self }, formats: [:html], layout: false).html_safe, header_html: Rails.root + 'app/views/field_set_answers/pdf_header.html.haml')
    pdf_kit.stylesheets << "#{Rails.root}/public/stylesheets/feedback.css"
    file_name = "feedback_#{Time.now.to_i}.pdf"
    file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{file_name}"
    file = pdf_kit.to_file(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryied to something like this

```
pdf_kit = PDFKit.new(view_generator.render(partial: 'field_set_answers/pdf_feedback', :header_center => "foo", locals: { field_set_answer: self }, formats: [:html], layout: false).html_safe, header_html: Rails.root + 'app/views/field_set_answers/pdf_header.html.haml')
```